# Different pid of the java application when running using intellij idea

Tags: java, linux, pid

When i am running my application using some IDE say IntelliJ idea, and using a function in my application code to print the current process pid i get some different pid which is not visible using `ps aux` command.

I am using this function

```java
static void printCurrentPid(){
   long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
   System.out.println("PID:"+pid);
}
```

But when i run the jar of my application using cli, it prints the actual pid which is visible to kernel and can be seen using `jps` command.

Please help!

Comment: maybe use `ps efx`to better understand the process hierarchy.

Comment: Problem solved! actually i was using intelliJ installed via flatpack. I don't why it is creating its own namespace. Now using intelliJ IDE from snap store, its working fine. Thanks